# Building Chromium for Windows: Unable to start program "allocator_irt_x64". The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio, chromium

I followed the steps in the link below and I want to debuging in Chromium with VS2019, but I am encountering an error.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

ERROR:

Unable to start program "D:\chromium\src\out\Default\allocator_irt_x64".
The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

I've been dealing with this error for about 1 week and it didn't get fixed even though I completely reset my computer 4 times. When I did these operations for the first time, it worked albeit slowly, but I can't run it anymore.

When I checked the path in the Error, I noticed that the path specified does not exist. But I don't know how to fix this. Also, sometimes when I delete everything and reinstall, I get the error that "allocator_clang_newlib_x64" is not found and it still doesn't work.

Note: "gclient sync" didn't work.

[image]

Visual Studio Installer:

[image]

My command steps:

1. mkdir chromium && cd chromium
2. fetch --no-history chromium
3. cd src
4. gn gen --ide=vs --filters=//chrome out\Default
5. call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
   Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" out\Default\all.sln

Comment: Run `gclient sync` after fetching Chromium source code.

Comment: As I mentioned above this doesn't work. @Asesh